# postgres sql to find records with a sequence of status and dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

users table

```
id createdDate status
1  2021-03-10  Active
1  2021-03-05  Pending
1  2021-03-07  Failed
2  2020-09-20  Pending
2  2020-09-01  Active
2  2020-07-01  Failed
```

Looking for select sql that fetches records with **Active** status for IDs which have

1. all three **Active, Failed** and **Pending** statuses or
2. Active and Failed Statuses or
3. Active and Pending Statuses

and Active is the latest one(**createdDate**).

From above example I need result of

```
1  2021-03-10  Active
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by id and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id, MAX(createdDate) createdDate, 'Active' status
FROM tablename
WHERE status IN ('Active', 'Failed', 'Pending')
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(createdDate) = MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'Active' THEN createdDate END) -- the last date is the date with 'Active' status
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT status) >= 2 -- at least 2 statuses exist
```

If 'Active', 'Failed' and 'Pending' are the only possible values of the column `status` you may remove the `WHERE` clause.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5f160a907072485dd3330e57a52467c).

Comment: Just edited my question with refined requirements. please review it again. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have those three statuses, you can express this as:

```
select id
from users
group by id
having count(*) filter (where status in ('Pending', 'Failed')) > 0 and
       max(createdDate) = max(createdDate) filter (where status = 'Active');
```

The first condition checks that there is at least one pending or failed status.  The second checks that the maximum `createdDate` is the active `createdDate`.  It necessarily implies that there is at least one active status.

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table users (id int, createdDate date, status varchar(50));
 insert into users values(1,  '2021-03-10',  'Active');
 insert into users values(1,  '2021-03-05',  'Pending');
 insert into users values(1,  '2021-03-07',  'Failed');
 insert into users values(2,  '2020-09-20',  'Pending');
 insert into users values(2,  '2020-09-01',  'Active');
 insert into users values(2,  '2020-07-01',  'Failed');
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
   select id,createddate,status,row_number()over(partition by id order by createddate desc)rn from users
 )
 select id,createddate,status from cte a where rn=1 and status='Active'
 and exists (select 1 from cte b where a.id=b.id and b.status='Pending' )
 and exists (select 1 from cte b where a.id=b.id and b.status='Failed')
```

Output:

| id | createddate | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-10 | Active |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=574abc57967d8c74b78aaac1dd4450a8)*

Comment: Just edited my question with refined requirements. please review it again. thanks.